# Display multiple choice questions in a random order

Tags: java, random, eclipse-plugin

Below is the code that displays multiple choice questions sequentially.
It displays a question, gets the answer and checks for correctness.

```
  public static void Rap() {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int correct = 0;

  //1
  System.out.println("Complete the lyrics(hint travis scott): 'dont you open up that...  \n A.can of coke \n B.window \n C. back door \n D. water bottle ");
  String x = input.next();
  if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
   System.out.println("Correct");
   correct++;
  }
  if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
   System.out.println("incorrect");
  }
  if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
   System.out.println("incorrect");
  }
  if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
   System.out.println("incorrect");
  }
  //Same for other questions

  System.out.println("You got " + correct++ + "/15 good or bad job i guess");
```

Please suggest how to randomize this flow?

Comment: Think of one question as one object that might extend an abstract class. Add the objects to a list. Set the list as a model to an UI element.

Comment: if you create an object class to store your questions you can then store a list of type question and then access the questions via a random index and create a temp list for the answered questions so they dont come up twice in on run. id show you a start to this but i dont do `java`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are a beginner to programming, that's great!

From your code what I understand is: you have `n` number of questions displayed to the user and you want to keep count of correct answers.

Algorithmically,

```
for every question in n questions,
    display one question
    read the input
    if input is correct, increment the correct count
    display correct/incorrect
    go to next question
```

**Solution:**
This answer might look complex, but trust me, you will learn a lot of things here.

**First**, create a class to store your question and correct answer's option.

```
class Question {
    /*Read about private access specifier and getter/setter methods*/
    String question;
    String correctOption;
    public Question(String question, String correctOption) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctOption = correctOption;
    }
}
```

**Secondly**, create a list of these question objects (Read about array [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java) and Lists [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist))

```
List<Question> allQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();
allQuestions.add(new Question("YOUR_QUESTION", "CORRECT_OPTION"));
/*Example:*/
allQuestions.add(new Question("Complete the lyrics(hint travis scott): 'dont you open up that... \n A.can of coke \n B.window \n C. back door \n D. water bottle", "b"));
/* TODO do this for all the 15 questions*/
```

**Thirdly**, shuffle the `Question` objects in the `allQuestions`
    import java.util.Collections

```
Collections.shuffle(allQuestions);
```

**Finally**, follow the algorithm explained above:

```
//TODO prepare allQuestions as explained above
for (int i=0; i < allQuestions.size(); i++) {
    Question curQuest = allQuestions.get(i);
    System.out.println(curQuest.question)
    String ans = input.next();
    if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase(curQuest.correctOption)) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        correct++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("incorrect");
    }
}
System.out.println("You got "+ correct++ +"/15 good or bad job i guess");
```