# My app in android studio crashes when some code is executed

Tags: java, android, crash

When i launch the other activity, not the main activity, the application crashes.

I have tried to remove parts of the code on the activity "questions", to find out what part of the code causes this.

I am completely new to stackoverflow, and to android studio, and coding with javascript. I am trying to make this application, and found all of the code in the questions activity. I cannot code myself, but i am trying to learn it by googling.

The application has a clickable textview, which works. It did however not work when i added code taken from here: [Display multiple choice questions in a random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180643/display-multiple-choice-questions-in-a-random-order)

This is the code on the activity which crashes:

```
package com.example.myapplicationjava;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class questions extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        class Question {
            /*Read about private access specifier and getter/setter methods*/
            private String question;
            private String correctOption;
            private Question(String question, String correctOption) {
                this.question = question;
                this.correctOption = correctOption;
            }
        }


        List<Question> allQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
        allQuestions.add(new Question("YOUR_QUESTION", "CORRECT_OPTION"));
        /*Example:*/
        allQuestions.add(new Question("question \n A. answer1 \n B. answer2 \n C. answer3", "B"));
        /* TODO do this for all the 15 questions*/

        Collections.shuffle(allQuestions);

        //TODO prepare allQuestions as explained above
        int correct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < allQuestions.size(); i++) {
            Question curQuest = allQuestions.get(i);
            System.out.println(curQuest.question);
            String ans = input.next();
            if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase(curQuest.correctOption)) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                correct++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("incorrect");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You got "+ correct++ +"/15 good or bad job i guess");

    }
}
```

When this part of the code is not commented, starting this activity crashes the application:

```
//TODO prepare allQuestions as explained above
        int correct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < allQuestions.size(); i++) {
            Question curQuest = allQuestions.get(i);
            System.out.println(curQuest.question);
            String ans = input.next();
            if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase(curQuest.correctOption)) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                correct++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("incorrect");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You got "+ correct++ +"/15 good or bad job i guess");
```

I would expect the app to write to the terminal tab ?, but its empty. I also expected the app not to crash. Another post about an app crashing asked for the logcat log. Here it is:

```
2019-06-21 17:04:51.426 1634-1645/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.myapplicationjava/.questions} from uid 10080 on display 0

    --------- beginning of main
2019-06-21 17:04:51.435 1390-1412/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 7105255 , only wrote 7104960
2019-06-21 17:04:51.469 13313-13313/com.example.myapplicationjava I/System.out: YOUR_QUESTION
2019-06-21 17:04:51.470 13313-13313/com.example.myapplicationjava D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2019-06-21 17:04:51.470 13313-13313/com.example.myapplicationjava E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplicationjava, PID: 13313
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplicationjava/com.example.myapplicationjava.questions}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:874)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1388)
        at com.example.myapplicationjava.questions.onCreate(questions.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
2019-06-21 17:04:51.483 1634-1988/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.myapplicationjava/.questions
2019-06-21 17:04:51.528 1634-1988/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.myapplicationjava/.MainActivity
2019-06-21 17:04:51.613 1634-8411/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-06-21 17:04:51.613 1634-8411/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-06-21 17:04:51.614 1634-8411/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-06-21 17:04:51.614 1634-8411/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-06-21 17:04:51.621 1634-8411/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa00d92c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2019-06-21 17:04:51.637 1634-8411/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa00d92c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x889fe540)
2019-06-21 17:04:51.645 1634-8411/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa00d92c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x889fe540)
2019-06-21 17:04:52.029 1634-1647/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{7589e89 u0 com.example.myapplicationjava/.questions t37 f}
2019-06-21 17:04:52.180 2115-2267/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2b85300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2b83640)
2019-06-21 17:04:52.693 2115-2267/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
2019-06-21 17:04:54.662 1390-1413/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 7412695 , only wrote 7259760
2019-06-21 17:05:02.632 1634-1647/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{7589e89 u0 com.example.myapplicationjava/.questions t37 f}
2019-06-21 17:05:02.633 1634-1647/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{62c23a u0 com.example.myapplicationjava/.MainActivity t37 f}
2019-06-21 17:05:02.633 1634-1647/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.example.myapplicationjava/com.example.myapplicationjava.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2311 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeAllWindows:530 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeAppFromTaskLocked:326
```

Edit: The app still crashes when checking if the input.next is null:

```
//TODO prepare allQuestions as explained above
        int correct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < allQuestions.size(); i++) {
            Question curQuest = allQuestions.get(i);
            System.out.println(curQuest.question);
            String ans = input.next();
            if(ans != null && ans.equalsIgnoreCase(curQuest.correctOption)) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                correct++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("incorrect");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You got "+ correct++ +"/15 good or bad job i guess");
```

Some times the old log is displayed, when the YOUR_QUESTION example question is selected. When the other question is selected from the shuffle, this is the log:

```
2019-06-21 18:03:00.435 15047-15047/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.435 15047-15047/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-06-21 18:03:00.669 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/lib/x86
2019-06-21 18:03:00.679 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-06-21 18:03:00.767 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void com.example.myapplicationjava.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:16)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.816 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplicationjava-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void com.example.myapplicationjava.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:16)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
2019-06-21 18:03:00.817 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
2019-06-21 18:03:01.235 15047-15064/com.example.myapplicationjava I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-06-21 18:03:01.235 15047-15064/com.example.myapplicationjava D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-06-21 18:03:01.235 15047-15064/com.example.myapplicationjava W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-06-21 18:03:01.236 15047-15064/com.example.myapplicationjava D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-06-21 18:03:01.255 15047-15064/com.example.myapplicationjava D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9e3f39e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2019-06-21 18:03:01.306 15047-15064/com.example.myapplicationjava D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e3f39e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e3909e0)
2019-06-21 18:03:01.333 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
2019-06-21 18:03:01.342 15047-15064/com.example.myapplicationjava D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e3f39e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e3909e0)
2019-06-21 18:03:08.480 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/System.out: question 
2019-06-21 18:03:08.480 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/System.out:  A. answer1 
2019-06-21 18:03:08.480 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/System.out:  B. answer2 
2019-06-21 18:03:08.480 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava I/System.out:  C. answer3
2019-06-21 18:03:08.481 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2019-06-21 18:03:08.481 15047-15047/com.example.myapplicationjava E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplicationjava, PID: 15047
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplicationjava/com.example.myapplicationjava.questions}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:874)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1388)
        at com.example.myapplicationjava.questions.onCreate(questions.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I will probably attempts to remove the whole system.next stuff, and try to view the question in some other way, when more googling has been done. Thanks for all of the suggestions so far.

Comment: First, this is not Javascript, this is Java.
Second, why are you trying to use System.in in Android appliation?

Comment: I removed the Javascript tag. I am using system.in because that is what i found when i copy/pasted this code. I don't know what system.in does, but i just assumed it is needed to get input. I will probably not use system.in when i change this app to later accept input by tapping one of the mutiple choice answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like using `string ans = input.next()` caused the app to crash. I am not using input.next anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to call `input.next()` on the Scanner object, without checking if it actually has any other elements left, that's why you are getting a `NoSuchElementException`. Try this instead:

```
    if(input.hasNext()) {
        String ans = input.next();
        if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase(curQuest.correctOption)) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
            correct++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("incorrect");
        }
    }
```

This will make it not crash, you can see the logs in the Logcat, but it still doesn't function the way I imagine you wanted to.

Comment: I edited my code to include this check, but it still crashes. I also don't get the question as output in the terminal tab. I mean, the app havent crashed before asking for the question, so i should get this as output?

Comment: I think in the log you have I can see this: I/System.out: YOUR_QUESTION, so you are getting the log. When it crashes now, does it crash with the same exception?

Comment: Still crashes with the same exception, weird.